# Convert Training Graph to Inference Graph? ( Remove Batch Normalization in TF)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, batch-normalization

I have been trying to find tools that I can use to remove the batch normalization nodes during the inference phase.

I have used the graph transform tool that TF provides but they don't actually remove the batch norm layers. Just fuses it to the previous conv layers.

Does anyone have any tools that they use for this purpose?

I would be fine with  the batch layers, but tf life does not support it yet.

MobileNet seems to require batch normalization, so how is tflite being able to run MobileNet?

Answer (score 0):

When you convert your tensorflow graph to tflite graph, utility tflite_convert (or toco) automatically fused batch norm during conversation. This is part of conversion general transformations